# jQuery Context menu on osx?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, jquery-plugins, mouseevent

If I create a context menu with say [jQuery Context Menu Plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/) in a web site, how will that work with OSX computers using a single mouse button?

What terms should I use in the help texts not to confuse OSX users regardless of their type of mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOSX 10.5, Firefox (v5 and v0.8), Opera: works perfectly
Safari 5.0.6: doesn't work at all :(

If you have a single-button mouse, you can Ctrl-mouseclick for the context menu.